# application updating process

Tags: android

I develop my first android application, so i have a question about its updating.
What kind of notice will user get?
I set

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

in my manifest.
Have i to do anything else?
If i posted in market new version of my application with the same keystore and package name, increase versionCode and versionName,  will user automaticly get a notice on his phone? Or he will can see that update is availeble only when enters play market?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update your app, you have to increase the versionCode. User will get notice in his phone according to the settings he has set in his Google play app. User can even set to auto update apps. You can browse through the settings of the Google playstore app.

Answer (score 1):

If the user set the flag "download automatically " then when you upload the package the new version will get downloaded automatically. Otherwise he will get notified through the notification panel of new up date ( usually within 2 days of you uploading the package)

Make sure you activate the new version an deactivate the old one from developer consol.